# Replacing fragments in an activity not calling onAttach, onCreate, onCreateView, etc

Tags: java, android, fragment, fragmentmanager

So I have this piece of code here, I am creating a new Fragment and replacing it with another fragment. That works well. However I have notice that on the first line the constructor is being called but the `onAttach()`, `onCreate()` etc are not. If I were to uncomment the second line it won't work as `updateItem(URL)` requires a webView that is initiated in the onCreate() function.

```
DetailViewFragment detailFragment = new DetailViewFragment();
//detailFragment.updateItem(URL);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.displayList, detailFragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Would appreciate any help that will get that to work with the second line uncommented.

Comment: I believe that onAttach, onCreate, etc don't get called until the fragment has been committed to the Activity.  So they should be called on the last line of that code.  Android docs on lifecycle:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle Have you tried using ft.add(...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onAttach()`, `onCreate()`, etc. will not be called until the `FragmentManager` has actually committed the change.  So, some time after `commit()` is called on the transition. If you need to pass the URL to the `Fragment` from the start, add it to the fragment's argument bundle *before* you call `commit()`.  Then you'll be able to get access to the URL in your `onCreate()` or other lifecycle methods.  So you'll want something like this:

```
DetailViewFragment detailFragment = new DetailViewFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(DetailViewFragment.INIT_URL, URL);
detailFragment.setArguments(args);
ft.replace(R.id.displayList, detailFragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Now in your `onCreate()` you can call `getArguments()` to get the bundle and retrieve the URL which was passed by your activity.

Answer (score 4):

API Level 23 `onAttach(Context context)` works
API Level 22 `onAttach(Activity activity)` works

Implementing both methods worked for me:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to call `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` just after the commit. Beware that the transcation will be synchronous then.