# onAttach not called when rotation occures

Tags: android

Can someone tell me why `onAttach()` is not getting called on `Fragment` that have been replaced within `Activity` ?
`onDetach()` is working perfectly fine.

The reason why I am asking about that is because I'm trying to change `Toolbar` title when different `Fragments` are being replaced in `Activity`.

**EDIT**
My question is different because my `onAttach()` is getting called when `Fragment` is getting replaced, its not called however when rotation occurs.

Comment: are you adding the fragment back again when the activity recreates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing fragments in an activity not calling onAttach, onCreate, onCreateView, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956034/replacing-fragments-in-an-activity-not-calling-onattach-oncreate-oncreateview)

Comment: @Ata yes I do add it back when activity recreates, otherwise the question would not have had a point :)